# The difference between "do I sound like I am doing something," and "does it sound like I am doing something."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching Die Hard. John McClane had rushed to the roof of a building, and he was trying to talk to the police to ask for help by using some kind of radio signal, but his act was misunderstood to be a prank. He was angry and shouted at the policewoman on the radio. Here is what he said to the policewoman:

> "Do I sound like I am ordering a pizza?"

I am wondering why it was not,

> Does it sound like I am ordering a pizza

Do the two sentences make any difference in meaning?

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference in meaning in this particular case. Perhaps the second option "Does it sound like I am ordering a pizza" is in fact preferable, because there is no unnecessary repetition of "I". It would be different if there were no 2nd clause "like I am ordering a pizza". In that case "Does it sound", and "Do I sound" would have different meanings, but considering there is the clause which defines sound, meaning remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, idiomatic ways of asking the question.

Both utterances boil down to much the same thing: the speaker is impatient with the listener for the listener's failure to grasp the situation.

If someone asks:

> Do *I* sound like I'm {joking|ordering a pizza|etc}?

the speaker is referring to himself or herself as a *person* who is speaking at this moment, and the listener is being chastised as a poor judge of *people speaking*.

If someone asks:

> Does *it* sound like I'm {joking|ordering a pizza|etc}?

the speaker is referring to the *impression* his or her words are making on the listener, and the listener is being chastised as a poor judge of *speaking people*.

:)